# How can I program a NVIDIA brightness slider like the Volume slider?

Tags: c#, windows-7, nvidia

I like how you can quickly adjust the volume by clicking the icon and then scrolling the mouse wheel,
how can I write something similar for the NVIDIA brightness (not the backlight of my laptop screen)?

[image]

I'm tired of different video black levels which take down their quality,
this would allow me to quickly adjust it and a mute button would serve as a way to reset it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do this using [NVAPI](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nvapi.html), the same interface the NVIDIA Control Panel uses. I haven't tested to be sure, but the `NvAPI_VIO_SetGamma` function sounds like a good starting point.

Comment: It looks like you have to sign an NDA to get access to these functions.

Comment: No, there's a public version at the bottom of the page. The NDA version exposes more functionality, but you shouldn't need it for this.

Answer (score 1):

NvAPI_GetVideoState & 
NvAPI_SetVideoState
;)